# nth child floating in columns

Tags: css

I have this html here

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">explorers</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to take the first three and float it left in a left column and the last three floated right. 
I can't get it to work, they align all off and do not appear in the correct order. I marked up the CSS like this:

```
li:nth-child(-n+3) {float: left;}, 
li:nth-child(n+4) {float: right;}
```

What am I missing?
thanks!

edited to add the html link: [HERE IS THE PAGE](http://kimwilddesigns.com/TrailGuide_website/TrailGuide_website-class/index_fluid.html)

Comment: Is that comma at the end of your first line a mistake in the question? Otherwise it's the cause of one of your display errors.

Comment: Define work, what is it you want/expect to be seeing?

Comment: Sorry, the page is here: http://kimwilddesigns.com/TrailGuide_website/TrailGuide_website-class/index_fluid.html
scale it down to a smartphone width, I'd like to get the list in 2 columns. with home tours and mission on the first column. I put the background color in there just to visually see it better. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add for future reference, floats cause a reverse order item. Simple fix being, order your items backwards, but that's not obviously very practical.

Answer (score 1):

I [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/DZnHE/) a bit with CSS3 columns. It's surprisingly simple, actually:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;

    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
}
```

Basically, you define two columns on the containing list so that the first list items get placed in the first column and the others end up in the second column. By default, browsers set the spacing between columns to about `1em`, so you need to set that to `0` as well to collapse that space.

As you may expect, [browser support for this is limited to modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) such as Firefox 1.5+, Safari 3+, Chrome, IE10 and Opera 11.1+.

If you want to adjust the balancing between the columns, you can use `column-break-before` to force a column break before a certain element. For example, if you want only two items in the first column and the rest in the second column, you could add this snippet:

```
li:nth-child(3) {
    -moz-column-break-before: always;
    -webkit-column-break-before: always;
    column-break-before: always;
}
```

Unfortunately, only Safari 3+, Chrome, IE10 and Opera 11.1 support `column-break-before` at the time of writing. Firefox has yet to implement this feature.

Comment: HI,Thanks for this suggestion and for responding! I was trying to use simply nth child for the reason that css3 columns are not widely supported yet. So I guess its not possible?

Comment: @Kim I'm afraid not. You can do a lot with floats, but they fall short when the desired display order differs greatly from source order.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use nth child. Here is an example I ran across recently. It is set up for a number of screen widths and adjusts accordingly:  http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/xkcBn

It uses a simple unordered list.